# Java Object Set value for field by field name

Tags: java, android

I have a object this look like:

```
public class RM {
    private int id;
    private String name;
    private String being_in_force_dt;
    private String modify_dt;
    private AREA AREA;
    private String vehicle;
}
```

A date from this object I have in xml  and now I have a probleme how I can put a value to field for example name , when I have a :

```
String attName = xpp.getAttributeName(i); // here String = name
xpp.getAttributeValue(i) // and here is a value
```

I did this :

```
  if(attName.equals("id"))
                                rm.setId(Integer.parseInt(xpp.getAttributeValue(i)));
```

But maybe is better soluttion

Comment: You could use a [`HashMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html), then write *one* setter and *one* getter function, like `setAttribute(String attr, String value)`.

Comment: Read about reflection. Or better about JAXB mapper.

Comment: Using an XML<->java mapper (like JAXB, CASTOR or alike) based on a XSD is the best approach.

Comment: @talex ok but I did this on android ...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Object XML mapping in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16567925/object-xml-mapping-in-android)

Comment: Add `android` tag then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Java Reflection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37628/what-is-reflection-and-why-is-it-useful), is not a beautiful solution but works:

```
    RM obj = new RM();
    Field f = obj.getClass().getDeclaredField("id");
    f.setAccessible(true);
    f.set(obj, 1);

    Assert.assertEquals(1, obj.getId());
```

I suggest you to read about [JAXB](https://www.mkyong.com/java/jaxb-hello-world-example/).

Comment: You might want to add a link to the [Java Tutorials](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/index.html) or a SO question like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37628/what-is-reflection-and-why-is-it-useful)

Comment: Sure, this is a very simple example:
https://www.mkyong.com/java/jaxb-hello-world-example/

In the example annotations are on getter methods but you can also use it on privale field adding @XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD) on class

Comment: I wanted to suggest to just put these into the answer itself, so every reader can easily look these things up. I took the liberty to edit your question accordingly, I hope that's fine with you :-)

Comment: ok sorry i didn't understand I'm in a hurry :) I'll keep that in mind ;)

Answer (score 1):

**One possible solution is to use a [`HashMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html) for your attributes.**
Not exactly the most versatile approach, but certainly very easy to implement:

```
public class RM {
    private HashMap<String, String> attributes = new HashMap<>();

    public void setAttribute(String attr, String val) {
        attributes.put(attr, val);
    }

    public String getAttribute(String attr) {
        attributes.get(attr);
    }
}
```

And then later on:

```
rm = new RM();
rm.setAttribute(xpp.getAttributeName(i), xpp.getAttributeValue(i));
```

However, this will use `String` for all values. This might be okay, as you probably get strings from XML anyway. It would then be up to the user of the `RM` class to decide what to do with the values retrieved via `getAttribute()`.